# How to say Datetime - timestamp without time zone in EF Core 6.0

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I migrate an ASP.NET Core project from 3.1 to 6.0.

I have copied old migration and pasted it to our new version

Migration on EF Core 3.1 (old)

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "CalendarStartDate",
                table: "DealOverview",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
```

Migration in EF Core 6.0 (new)

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "StartDate",
                table: "DealOverview",
                type: "timestamp without time zone",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
                oldType: "timestamp with time zone");
```

The migration fails because this line

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

has changed.

I went from this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.4" />
```

to this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.1" />
```

Comment: _"The migration fails"_ what error do you have?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EF Core 6 Npgsql has introduced some [breaking changes](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#timestamp-rationalization-and-improvements) to timestamp handling logic. You can try to "revert" back to old behaviour by adding next line either to `Startup` or `Program` file:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

But in general it is recommended to migrate to the new behaviour.

Comment: Do you know how to use DateOnly type? When I do it creates this date in database: `292269055-12-02`.

Comment: Is there a way pass this without using context?

Comment: @Vivekkushwaha not, that I know of. But what is the problem with using `AppContext`?

Comment: @Guru Stron I am upgrading aws lambdas from .net core 3.1 to .net 6, where the connections are created as per need. we are not using entity framework.

Comment: @Vivekkushwaha `AppContext` is not related to EF, it's [`System.AppContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Guru Stron thanks for pointing it out, I thought AppContext  in the context of EF.